# Scrape data from all columns into python using selenium to load more

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape 1853 rows of data using selenium webdriver. After receiving some help on stack the code generates 1080 rows, but after the first 400 skips from ..09 to ..65 doesn't load in data. For example the output foes from

```
1008 Cartesi  CTSI/DAI  $10,426  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1009 WETH  WETH/LION  $10,178  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1065 WETH  WETH/DFIO  $7,823  0.00%  -  Percentage  Recently
1066 YAMv2  YAMv2/WETH  $7,794  0.00%  -  Percentage  106 days ago
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/exchanges/uniswap-v2/')

total_height = int(driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight"))
for x in range(20):
    time.sleep(2)
    for i in range(1, total_height, 130):
            time.sleep(1)
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(i))
    if x == 0:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.cmc-cookie-policy-banner__close').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text() = "Load More"]').click()


time.sleep(2)

first_column = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('td.cmc-table__cell.cmc-table__cell--sticky.cmc-table__cell--sortable.cmc-table__cell--left.cmc-table__cell--sort-by__rank > div')
second_column = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.cwwgik-0.bCvAgC')
third_column = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.hmd6df-0.kCRNNr')
fourth_column = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.cmc-table__column-market-pair-volume-24h')
fifth_column = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.cmc-table__column-market-pair-volume-percent')
sixth_column = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('td.cmc-table__cell.cmc-table__cell--sortable.cmc-table__cell--right.cmc-table__cell--sort-by__quote-usd-effective-liquidity > div')
seventh_column = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('td.cmc-table__cell.cmc-table__cell--sortable.cmc-table__cell--right.cmc-table__cell--sort-by__fee-type > div')
eighth_column = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.ghkc60-0.fLaXDt')

print(len(second_column))
it = 1
for i in range(len(second_column)):
    it+=1
    print(str(first_column[i].get_attribute("innerText")) + ' ' + str(second_column[i].get_attribute("innerText")) + '  ' + str(third_column[i].get_attribute("innerText")) + '  ' + str(fourth_column[i].get_attribute("innerText")) + '  ' + str(fifth_column[i].get_attribute("innerText")) + '  ' + str(sixth_column[i].get_attribute("innerText")) + '  ' + str(seventh_column[i].get_attribute("innerText")) + '  ' + str(eighth_column[i].get_attribute("innerText")))

print(it)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all<sup>*</sup>  the data with requests and hit the API endpoint the page uses. Alter the limit param to the maximum (use a loop and alter the start param if you need more than the limit allows). In this case you can get all results with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from pprint import pprint

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get('https://web-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/exchange/market-pairs/latest?aux=num_market_pairs,category,fee_type,market_url,currency_name,currency_slug,effective_liquidity&convert=USD,BTC&limit=5000&market_status=active&slug=uniswap-v2&start=1',
                  headers = headers)
data = r.json()['data']['market_pairs']
print(len(data))
pprint(data)
```

---

You could write a custom function to generate all the entries to output on a pair per row basis. TODO: Some formatting of columns e.g. number to percentage, drop any you don't want as more come back from json, rename + re-order any as desired.

Example formatting and renaming:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from pprint import pprint
import pandas as pd

def get_row(item):
    d = {}

    for k,v in item.items():
        if k in ['market_pair_base', 'market_pair_quote', 'quote']:
            for nk, nv in v.items():
                if k == 'quote':
                    for nnk, nnv in nv.items():
                        d[k +'-' + nk + '-' + nnk] = nnv
                else:
                    d[k +'-' + nk] = nv
        else:
            d[k] = v
    return d
        
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get('https://web-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/exchange/market-pairs/latest?aux=num_market_pairs,category,fee_type,market_url,currency_name,currency_slug,effective_liquidity&convert=USD,BTC&limit=5000&market_status=active&slug=uniswap-v2&start=1',
                  headers = headers)
data = r.json()['data']['market_pairs']
print(len(data))
results = [get_row(item) for item in data]
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df['Rank'] = [i for i in range(1, len(data) + 1)]
to_keep = ['Rank','market_pair_base-currency_name', 'market_pair', 'quote-USD-price', 
           'quote-USD-volume_24h', 'quote-USD-effective_liquidity', 'category', 'fee_type',
           'quote-USD-last_updated']
df = df[to_keep]
df = df.astype({'quote-USD-effective_liquidity': 'int64'})
df['quote-USD-volume_24h'] = df['quote-USD-volume_24h'].apply(lambda x: f"${int(x):,}")
df['quote-USD-price'] = df['quote-USD-price'].apply(lambda x: f"${x :.2f}")
df.rename(columns = {
                    'market_pair_base-currency_name' : 'Currency', 
                    'market_pair' : 'Pair',
                    'quote-USD-price': 'Price',
                    'quote-USD-volume_24h' : 'Volume (24h)',
                    'quote-USD-effective_liquidity' : 'Liquidity',
                    'category' : 'Category',
                    'fee_type' : 'Fee Type',
                    'quote-USD-last_updated' : 'Updated'
                      }, 
         inplace = True)
df.head(5)
# df.to_csv('data.csv', encoding = 'utf-8-sig', index=False)
```

<sup>*</sup> I assume `Volume (%)` is a calculated measure using values from columns within the returned json? You could print `results[0]` and investigate?

Example dict within results:

```
{'uniswap_info_url': 'https://info.uniswap.org/pair/0x0d4a11d5eeaac28ec3f61d100daf4d40471f1852',
 'dextool_url': 'https://www.dextools.io/app/uniswap/pair-explorer/0x0d4a11d5eeaac28ec3f61d100daf4d40471f1852',
 'outlier_detected': 0,
 'exclusions': None,
 'market_pair_base-exchange_symbol': 'WETH',
 'market_pair_base-currency_symbol': 'WETH',
 'market_pair_base-currency_id': 2396,
 'market_pair_base-currency_name': 'WETH',
 'market_pair_base-currency_slug': 'weth',
 'market_pair_base-currency_type': 'cryptocurrency',
 'market_pair_quote-exchange_symbol': 'USDT',
 'market_pair_quote-currency_symbol': 'USDT',
 'market_pair_quote-currency_id': 825,
 'market_pair_quote-currency_name': 'Tether',
 'market_pair_quote-currency_slug': 'tether',
 'market_pair_quote-currency_type': 'cryptocurrency',
 'quote-exchange_reported-price': 2667.608286932708,
 'quote-exchange_reported-volume_24h_base': 127187.96129018,
 'quote-exchange_reported-volume_24h_quote': 339287659.535759,
 'quote-exchange_reported-last_updated': '2021-05-27T03:48:07.000Z',
 'quote-BTC-price': 0.0713253375594862,
 'quote-BTC-volume_24h': 9071.724272524909,
 'quote-BTC-effective_liquidity': 0.024501313774380872,
 'quote-BTC-last_updated': '2021-05-27T03:55:02.000Z',
 'quote-USD-price': 2672.102873016602,
 'quote-USD-volume_24h': 339859316.77661276,
 'quote-USD-effective_liquidity': 917.9070603711,
 'quote-USD-last_updated': '2021-05-27T03:48:07.000Z',
 'market_id': 53239,
 'market_pair': 'WETH/USDT',
 'category': 'spot',
 'fee_type': 'percentage',
 'market_url': 'https://app.uniswap.org/#/swap?inputCurrency=0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2&outputCurrency=0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7'}
```